# How to detect/specify when no mysql data is returned from a nodejs query

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, express

I am trying to detect when nodejs receives no data back from a mysql query. If the data that is put through a GET request is correct, it gives back the desired results.

Working Request:

```
http://server.com:8000?a=userinfo&user=datathatmatchesvalueindb
```

Non-Working Request

```
http://server.com:8000?a=userinfo&user=datathatdoesn'tmatchanythinginthedb
```

**By non-working, I mean if the request includes data that is not in the mysql table, it displays a blank white page, instead of the desired result of 'no data'.**

In PHP if you want to detect if there is no data in the mysql row, you can do the following:

```
if($res->num_rows === 0)
{
    echo 'no data';
} else {
//Do you functions here
}
```

Is there an equivalent for nodejs code?

Here is the code I have written:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var database = require('mysql-simple');

app.get('/', function(req, res){

database.init('user', 'pass', 'db', 'IP');
var data = '';
if (req.query.a == 'userinfo') {
var q = 'SELECT * FROM `addrbook` WHERE `key` =\''+req.query.user+'\'';
} else if (req.query.a == 'facebook') {
var q = 'SELECT * FROM `addrbook` WHERE `facebook` =\''+req.query.fb+'\' OR `facebookp` =\''+req.query.fb+'\'';
} else if (req.query.a == 'youtubeurl') {
var q = 'SELECT * FROM `addrbook` WHERE `youtubeurl1` =\''+req.query.url+'\' OR     `youtubeurl2` =\''+req.query.url+'\' OR `youtubeurl3` =\''+req.query.url+'\'';
} else {
var q = 'SELECT * FROM `addrbook` WHERE `key` =\''+req.query.user+'\'';
}
database.query(q, function(err, rows, fields)
{
   if (err) {
    console.log('error fetching user data: ' + err);
    return;
  }
    //console.log(results);
   for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = rows[i];
    if(rows.length > 0) {
        var key = row['key'];
        var fb = row['facebook'];
        var daddr = row['addr'];
        if (req.query.a == 'userinfo') {

        data = JSON.stringify(row);
        res.write(data);

        } else if (req.query.a == 'facebook') {

        data = JSON.stringify(daddr);
        res.write(data);

        } else if (req.query.a == 'youtubeurl') {

        data = JSON.stringify(daddr);
        res.write(data);

        } else {
        res.write('no data');
        }
    } else {
        res.write('no data');
        console.log('no data');
    }
   }
    res.end();
});

});
app.listen(8000);
```

Comment: check to be sure you are using `res.send()` to get data out, and call `next()` to keep the response chain going.

Comment: Can you clarify more on next()?

Comment: Take a look in the [expressjs API](http://expressjs.com/api.html) and seach for "next()". It's really a middleware thing to keep response flow going. You may not need it (at least for now).

Comment: So far I don't believe I need it, though I will try and implement it. Do you have any idea why it won't display 'no data' when the mysql query returns no nothing for no data in existing in a row?

Answer (score 1):

Because your `res.write("no data")` is inside loop `for...rows` and as there are no rows it is never called.